# Getting a variable inside foreach from PHP to JS after localization

Tags: javascript, wp-enqueue-script, php, wp-localize-script

I believe I have properly enqueue'ed and localized my script - I've got $q showing up in the DOM.  Now I'm sure I'm missing the simple last step to accessing a variable in the JS function.

Here's my PHP:

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'sdm_load_javascript_files' );
function sdm_load_javascript_files() {

  wp_register_script( 'showMake', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/functions.js', array('jquery'), '1.1.0', true );

  wp_enqueue_script( 'showMake', get_template_directory_uri().'/js/functions.js', array( 'jquery' ) );
  $inventory_makes = get_inventory_makes();
  wp_localize_script(  'showMake', 'q', $inventory_makes );

}


function get_inventory_makes() {
  global $wpdb;
  $inventory_makes = $wpdb->get_results
    ("
      SELECT COUNT(inventory_id) as count_car, inventory_make
      FROM wp_dsfbjd_wpinventory_item
      GROUP BY inventory_make
    ");
  return $inventory_makes;
}
```

And here's part of my template where I think I'm missing what I need:

```
<ul>
  <?php
    $inventory_makes = get_inventory_makes();
    foreach ( $inventory_makes as $make )
    {            echo '<li><a onclick="showMake(q.inventory_make)">',$make->inventory_make,'&nbsp;(',$make->count_car,')','</a></li>';
    }
  ?>
</ul>
```

And lastly, my js function:

```
function showMake() {

  console.log(q.inventory_make);

}
```

And the DOM:
[image: *]

When I click on the HTML element, my console logs 'undefined' - after I've got access to the q.inventory_make I'll refresh the list of cars to show the make clicked.

Thanks in advance for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: what does the structure of `q` look like in the DOM? You iterate over it with `foreach` in PHP, accessing `inventory_make` as a member of each `$make` object, but then in JS you try to access `inventory_make` as if it's a direct child of `q`.

Comment: Thanks, Milo.  That's exactly what it is.  There's an extra layer.  I'm a JS rookie - is it q.object.inventory_make?

Comment: I added a screenshot above.  Happy to do some learning if you've got a link to point me in the right direction as well.

Answer (score 1):

You have `wp_enqueue_script( 'showMake' );` twice. Remove the last line from your sdm_load_javascript_files function and see if it works.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I removed it and it is still showing 'undefined' in the console when I click on the make.